# Flutter Listview items not rendering

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, state, statefulwidget

What I do is **fetching** items from Firebase then saving them in a list and then I display them in a **ListView**. **The Problem** that I have now is that I check if the list has Items and if so it displays my ListView with the Items and if there are no items it displays a Text but even **but even if there are items the text gets displayed** but **after pressing hot reload** the items get shown.

**My guess was that there is a Problem with the State of the Widgets overall because stuff like SetState has no effect or a Refresh Indicator**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why the `StreamBuilder` is following your `masterListStart().asStream` as opposed to the `masterList` stream? I'm not saying it's wrong, its just not immediately obvious.

Either way, it's not rebuilding automatically because the only part of your `displayStory` method that is reactive to the stream doesn't get built until after the non empty list condition is met. Without implementing a reactive state management solution there's nothing in your code that automatically notifies any listeners that the state of the `storysList` has changed, which means nothing is triggering a rebuild. Which is why you have to hot reload to see the changes.

Without me getting too deep into your code, try returning the `StreamBuilder` at the top level of the `displayStory` method and putting all the conditionals inside its its `builder` method.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer, regarding the thing you said about the stream builder I did it that way because I saw it like this on YouTube and didn't know there is something I could do different. And Regarding the second thing you suggested I will definitely try it out and keep you updated thanks

Comment: I love you it works, I can't tell you how much time I had to invest because I tried using set state and then I thought about statemangemnt but statemangemnt was to complex for me etc.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I suggest reading [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-firestore-you-may-be-using-it-wrong-b56fa689e489) about cleaning up your Firestore code. You have a ton of logic in your UI code and this will help clean it up. And generally, taking the time to learn a state management solution will only make things easier for you going forward. Provider or GetX is really not any more complex than learning how to use Firestore.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely have a look into Statemanagment because I also have a second problem with the streambuilder duplicating items when they are updated I hope state management will solve this

Comment: I should use Statemanagment because I can tell the App which Widget changes and what to do right?

Comment: Yep. For example with GetX you could make that `dispayStory` list into an observable `RxList`, and react to changes to its state.